# Dúvida sobre imagens em Latex

Tags: latex

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \graphicspath[scale = 0.2]{/Desktop/Universidade/2017li1g013/relatorio/Imagens/haddock.png}
    \caption{Documentação Haddock}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

Quero inserir uma imagem a partir de uma diretoria. No entanto no PDF não aparece o texto que coloquei para achar a imagem. Qual é o erro que estou a cometer?

Comment: Que texto? E a imagem, aparece?

Comment: Aparece [scale = 0.2]{/Desktop/Universidade/2017li1g013/relatorio/Imagens/haddock.png

Comment: @JoãoSampaio, pdflatex? O path the imagem parece estranho.  Talvez algo como `/home/joaoSampaio/Desktop/Uni......../haddock.png` ou usar um path relativo. (experimenta copiar a imagem para o mesma pasta e usar apenas `haddock.png`)